# Relation between square of sub-tangent and sub-normal of $y^2 = (x+a)^3$

Tags: derivatives, applications

If the relation between sub-tangent and sub-tangent at any point on the curve $y^2 = (x+a)^3$ is $p(SN)=q(ST)^2$ then find the value of $p:q$ where $SN$ is length of sub-normal and $ST$ is length of sub-tangent respectively.

Comment: For http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832132/what-are-the-roots-of-the-given-trigonometric-equation,     Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html,

  $$\cos5x-\cos x\sin5x=\cos x\{1-12\sin^2x+16\sin^4x-(5\sin x-20\sin^3x+16\sin^5x)\}$$

Comment: Please pardon me I have deleted that question. Please don't ask/ tell me any more about that question, lab bhattacharjee sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $SN$ is length of sub-normal and $ST$ is length of sub-tangent. 
Let us find slope which is nothing but $dy/dx$ at any point. Let the point be $(f,g)$
$y^2 = (x+a)^3$
$ 2 y dy/dx = 3(x+a)^2$
$dy/dx=[3(x+a)^2]/2y$
$dy/dx at (f,g) = 3(f+a)^2 /2g=m$ 
$SN=g.m= 3(f+a)^2 /2$
$ST=g/m= 2g^2 / [3(f+a)^2] = 2/3 (f+a)$
$(ST)^2 = 4/9 (f+a)^2 =4/9 . 2/3 (SN)$
$(ST)^2 = 8/27 (SN)$
$8(SN)=27(ST)^2$ 
$p$=8 and $q$=27
So $p:q$= 8$:$27